# (type=Bad Request, status=400) Required request parameter 'productId' for method parameter type long is not present (Spring MVC - Hibernate JPA)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

There is a problem about jpa hibernate (crud operation),Actually I can do create,read and delete operations,but when I met update operations I dont know what I should do.
This my code.And there is problem in update operation. Can you help me?

```
@Autowired
ProductRepository productRepository;

//**************WELCOME***************
@GetMapping("/welcome")
public String welcomePage() {
    return "welcome";
}

// **************İNSERT****************
@GetMapping(path = { "/productinsert"})
public String insertProduct(Model model) {
    Product product = new Product(" ", 0.0); // Gösterim Katmanına ilk boş bir sayfa gitmeli o yüzden değerler boş
    model.addAttribute("product", product);
    return "/productinsert";
}

@PostMapping("/productinsert")
public String insertProduct(Product product, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    productRepository.save(product);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "/productinsert";
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("mesaj", "Ürününüz Başarıyla Kaydedilmiştir.");
        return "/productsuccess";
    }
}

//************UPDATE**************
@GetMapping("/productedit")
public String editProduct() {
    return "/productedit";
}
***//PROBLEM İS HERE//***
@RequestMapping(value = "/productedit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editProductt(@RequestParam long productId, Model model) {
    Optional<Product> proOptional =  productRepository.findById(productId);
    Product product = proOptional.get();
    model.addAttribute("product", product);
    return "/productinsert";
}
```

}

AND PROBLEM İS THAT

There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required request parameter 'productId' for method parameter type long is not present
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'productId' for method parameter type long is not present

Answer (score 0):

This error mean you are missing **productId** parameter in your request, the request must have format `https://your-domain:port/productedit?productId=X`, example: `https://localhost:8080/productedit?productId=1`

Comment: Is this Minh from Verra?

Answer (score 0):

Used a `@RequestParam` annotations used a:

```java
@GetMapping("/fetchData) 
public Employee FindById(@RequestParam int id) {
    Optional<Employee> optional = er.findById(id);
    Employee employee = optional.get();
    return employee;
}
```